# Display list of values in database

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$sql   = "SELECT * FROM themes";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $id           = $row["id"];
    $name         = $row["name"];
    $developers   = $row["developers"];
    $description  = $row["description"];
    $category     = $row["category"];
    $logo         = $row["logo"];
    $officialLink = $row["link"];

    //////////////////////

    $sql          = "SELECT * FROM file WHERE software_id = '$id'";
    $query        = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $version = $row["version"];
        $file    = $row["file"];
        $link    = $row["link"];
        $created = $row["created"];

        $versions .= '<li><a href="../files/' . $file . '"                                target="_blank">
<i class="fa fa-mail-forward">
</i> ' . $version . '</a></li>';
        $logos = "<img src ='../img/logos/{$logo}' >";
    }

    //////////////////////

    $solfList .= '
                <li>
                <h3>' . $name . '</h3>

                </li>
                ';

}
```

This code displays only one value. I want to display all values stored in table. I have got this code. but I can't understand where I have made a mistake.

Comment: Look at the two query statements. By running the inner query you're losing all the outer query result set.

Comment: Use $solfList =''; before while loop .. ist while

Comment: i imagine you probably also want either `$logos[] = ...` or `$logos .= ...`

Answer (score 1):

Because of using same variable in both the `sql` you are losing the values of first loop. So use two different variable of both of queries and their results.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM themes";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
            while ($row_outer = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
            $id = $row_outer["id"];
            $name = $row_outer["name"];
            $developers = $row_outer["developers"];
            $description = $row_outer["description"];
            $category = $row_outer["category"];
            $logo = $row_outer["logo"];
            $officialLink = $row_outer["link"];
            //////////////////////
            $solfList = "";
            $sql_inner = "SELECT * FROM file WHERE software_id = '$id'";
            $query_inner = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql_inner); 
                while ($row_inner = mysqli_fetch_array($query_inner, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
                $version = $row_inner["version"];
                $file = $row_inner["file"];
                $link = $row_inner["link"];
                $created = $row_inner["created"];
                    $versions .='<li><a href="../files/' .$file. '"                                target="_blank">
<i class="fa fa-mail-forward">
</i> ' .$version. '</a></li>';
                    $logos = "<img src ='../img/logos/{$logo}' >";
            }
                    //////////////////////
                $solfList .='
                <li>
                <h3>' .$name. '</h3>

                </li>
                ';

            }
```

Comment: @urfusion It's not about the variable `$sql`, it's about the outer result set getting destroyed by the inner result set. The variable `$sql` can be re-used again.

Answer (score 0):

Just like I said, by running the inner query you're losing all the outer query result set. So your code should be like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM themes";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
$id = $row["id"];

// your code

$sql = "SELECT * FROM file WHERE software_id = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
        $version = $r["version"];

        // your code

    }

    // your code

}
```